# why I get error when test my code in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org),and [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) to test the code.

connecting to mongodb :

```
if (!!connection) {
    model = connection.model('client', clientSchema, collections.clients[env]);
} else {
    model = mongoose.model('client', clientSchema, collections.clients[env]);
}
```

This is the unit tests:

```
describe('Bad VSA card test', () => {

    it('should contains VSA accounts', async (done) => {
        const vsaCard =  await updatedVSA();
        console.log(vsaCard);
        expect(vsaCard.length).to.equal(5);
        done();
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        client.disconnect();
    });

});
```

When I run this test code, I get an error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Actually, I searched for this error first. And I found a similar issue. His error was fixed by closing db connection. Why am I still getting this error by closing MongoDB connection?

Comment: Can you please specify what client library / DB you are using?

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. Can you add the way that you're connecting to mongo (mongoose?) - would be good to see the file as a whole (without your DB credentials)

Comment: Have you tried with using `done` this is usually not necessary when using `async/await`

Comment: Are  you ever actually connecting to the db?  If so, you're not showing it in the code here.

Comment: Have you tried actually running it with `--detectOpenHandles`? I had to do this on mine, I had no obvious open connections, and this prevented it from throwing more erros